# how to get image id in juypter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
base_skin_dir = os.path.join(r'C:\Users\teff\input', 'skin-cancer-mnist-ham10000')

imageid_path_dict = {os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(x))[0]: x
                     for x in glob(os.path.join(base_skin_dir, '*', '*.jpg'))}

print(imageid_path_dict)


lesion_type_dict = {
    'nv': 'Melanocytic nevi',
    'mel': 'Melanoma',
    'bkl': 'Benign keratosis-like lesions ',
    'bcc': 'Basal cell carcinoma',
    'akiec': 'Actinic keratoses',
    'vasc': 'Vascular lesions',
    'df': 'Dermatofibroma'
}
```

I have used above code to get image id from destination C:\Users\teff\input\skin-cancer-mnist-ham10000 
but i am getting output as - { }

Don't know why please help

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Reading your code, I don't really understand what command should « get image id but returns `{}` », could you please provide it?

Comment: I have two zip file inside this folder which contains jpg file which should be returned but it is returning null value

Comment: You're only globbing on `jpg` extensions; that will likely not find any zip files.

Comment: JPEG files are generally compressed already; no need to create a zip file out of them. Things may be easier if you just store and use the actual JPEG files, and remove the zip files.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "image id"? Some number, filename, path, ...?